# Can someone please correct me with this sub-netting scenario?

Tags: ipv4, ip, subnet, ip-address

quick question! I've been told to figure out what was wrong with the the configurations on the devices. Ive come to the conclusion that all subnet masks should be 255.0.0.0 but have been told that all devices should be 255.255.255.0. I'm confused, aren't they Class A addresses, why would they be 255.255.255.0?

[image]

Comment: Why would you configure the hosts with larger subnet masks, when Router 1 defines the subnet as /24 or 255.255.255.0 and Router 1 is the gateway for that network?

Comment: Sounds like homework to me...

Comment: Forget network classes, they died in 1993 and are safely buried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Homework I guess? I'll answer generically so it might be useful to more people.

First: Forget about address classes. They haven't existed anymore for the last two decades.

In your example you're using addresses that are reserved for internet providers when using large scale NAT, but let's ignore that error in the exercise right now.

These days we use CIDR (classless inter domain routing). You use prefix lengths to define how many bits of the address belong to the network part and how many to the host part. A /8 corresponds to 255.0.0.0: the first 8 bits define the network, the rest the host. A /24 corresponds to 255.255.255.0: 24 bits for the network, rest for the host.

With IPv4 the first and last address of each network are reserved. We have to take that into account when looking at options.

Actually, the 255.255.255.0 or /24 answer is debatable as well because it provides much more addresses than you need, but it's very common and not a big deal with most networks using private IPv4 addresses. With public IPv4 addresses you can't be that wasteful these days. (Note that I'm explicitly saying IPv4 here, for IPv6 you'd need a different mindset)

A /24 gives you 8 bits for hosts, which allows for host addresses between 100.50.1.1 and 100.50.1.254 (remember that .0 and .255 are part of the network but reserved). It works but you'll only use .1, .11, .12 and .13. So quite a waste.

The optimal solution would be 100.50.1.0/28 (255.255.255.240). That would give you 4 bits for hosts, which allows for 16 addresses. Two are reserved, so you can use 100.50.1.1 to 100.50.1.14. That almost exactly covers the range you need on your network.

Comment: /28 doesn't almost cover it, it does cover it. :-)

Comment: .14 is still free :)

Answer (score 0):

What did they mean by "wrong"? What is wrong here?
Maybe the masks aren't the most efficient, but from a pure communication standpoint no issues at all regarding the PCs in question. how so?

Despite the different subnet-masks PC11, PC12 and PC13 will still see each other in the same LAN,
and be able to send traffic directly to each other wihtout the need for routing.

Lets take PC11 and PC12 for example:

PC11 asks himself is 100.50.1.12 a member of my network?

To figure this out I assume PC11 does the following test using his subnet mask:

[image]

*why not use the mask of the destination peer? - First of all, he doesn't have any knowledge of what it is.
                                                 Secondly, the mask is only important when sending data from the sender's standpoint.

So he finds out that PC12 is indeed in his own network and so it sends traffic directly to it.

From PC12's prespective, the same test is performed:

PC12 asks is 100.50.1.11 a member of my network?

[image]

PC12 also understands that PC11 is in its own network, and likewise sends traffic directly to it.

Lets consider something a bit more complex:

[image]

In this case PC11 still sees PC12 as a member of its network (using the test described above).
But PC12 doesn't see PC11 as such:

[image]

Doesn't equal.
So routing is required - but it won't work in this particular scenario, since the router itself will require routing to reach 100.50.2.11 (since it's not a member of its interface's network 100.50.1.0).